# Short story about computer breaking on purpose just to feel technician's touch

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It was a short story I've read somewhere in late 80s/early 90s: a boss yells at one of his technician, complaining that he is doing a poor job at repairing some sort supercomputer/phone exchange machine, since all jobs that he is sent to are quickly followed by another hardware failure. The boss intends to fire the poor guy, but gets electrocuted by his own phone. Then the technician hears from the speaker female voice saying that "she breaks on purpose, because she loves his tender touch on her most sensitive parts".